# Javascript __dopostback(): arguments passing error "Invalid postback or callback argument"

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I would like to raise an event in javascript from Asp.net code behind page; whenever a checkbox control is checked. I am able to use `__dopostback` from javascript to raise an event in the code behind, but I'm not able to pass a variable as argument.

This is the javascript code:

```
function CallServerCkhkBox(chkvalue) {
    alert("_dopostback " + chkvalue);
    __doPostBack('btnRefresh', chkvalue);
    //__doPostBack('btnRefresh', 'Blue Green');
}
```

The alert prints the correct value of the variable chkvalue.

This is the C# code behind:

```
protected void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string checkboxes;
    if (Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"] != "")
    {
        checkboxes = "From Javascript " + Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
    }
    else
    {
        checkboxes = "From Click " + hdnChkbval.Value;
    }           
    lblCheckBoxes.Text = checkboxes;
}
protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation("btnRefresh", "Blue Green");
    base.Render(writer);
}
```

If I pass an argument a fixed string to `__dopostback` it works, otherwise it returns the error:

> Invalid postback or callback argument.

I believe in the RegisterForEventValidation() method, the exact value is not declared.

Is there any way to pass a variable string?

Comment: please invest some time & learn how to post & format code before posting.

Comment: Use a hidden input and just before `__doPostBack` calling, set whatever value you want, and read that value at server-side

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function CallServerCkhkBox(chkvalue) {
    alert("_dopostback " + chkvalue);
    __doPostBack('btnRefresh', chkvalue.toString());
}
```